# What is the correct type annotation for this function?

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

I've got the following utility function, which should be self explanatory:

```lisp
(ns my.utility-belt
  "Use this everywhere."
  (:use clojure.core.typed))

(ann  zipfn (All [c a b ...] [[a b ... b -> c] (Seqable a) * -> (Seqable c)]))
(defn zipfn
  "Applies f to the interleaved elements of colls. If 2 colls are given, then f
  will recieve 2 arguments, one from each coll. If 3 colls are given, then f
  will receive 3 arguments, and so on. Returns a flat sequence of the results of
  applying f to its args."
  [f & colls]
  (map (partial apply f) (partition (count colls) (apply interleave colls))))

(comment
  (let [c1 [1 2 3 4 5]
        c2 [5 4 3 2 1]]
    (assert (= (zipfn * c1 c2)
               '(5 8 9 8 5)))))
```

The annotation I've provided isn't entirely correct, but I have no idea why. Calling `(check-ns)` just gives me "`Type Error (my/utility_belt.clj:12:51) Bad arguments to polymorphic function in apply in (apply interleave colls)`"

What's the correct type annotation in this case?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what does `zipfn` give you that using `map` directly does not? I can't seem to find any inputs that give them nonequal outputs.

Comment: @Magos `zipfn` combines an arbitrary number of collections into one collection. It's like a combo of `zipmap` and `map`.

Comment: Yes, but you then feed it into `map` which [already accepts any number of colls](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/map/). Is it something to do with `map` ceasing consumption when the smallest coll is emptied?

Comment: Hm, I didn't realize that `map` already accepted any number of colls *and* interleaved them, so it already does what I want. I've been doing clojure for 2 years and didn't realize this! I tested `map` on the code I originally needed `zipfn` for and it works the same :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is core.typed is having trouble inferring this is the actual type of `zipfn`. The quickest way to get around this is to tell core.typed to ignore the definition of `zipfn` with `:no-check`.

```
(ann ^:no-check zipfn (All [c a b ...] [[a b ... b -> c] (Seqable a) * -> (Seqable c)]))
```

Comment: Seriously? That's weird man... Anyway thanks. I guess I should read your thesis in order to really understand how core.typed is working :)

Comment: Unfortunately this definition quite hard to check as is. `apply` is special cased so it loses most of its expressivity in the type system if used in higher-order ways.